# EntityManager don't being injected by Guice

Tags: java, dependency-injection, persistence, guice

I updated my createInjector call to include my JPAPersisteModule...

`Guice.createInjector(new ApplicationModule(), new JpaPersistModule("simpleRestApplication"));`

On my service, my DAO is injected without problem...

```
@Path("/users")
public class UserService {

    @Inject
    private UserDAO dao;

    public UserService() {
        Application.getInjector().injectMembers(this);
    }


}
```

On my UserDAOImpl, the Provider dont get injected...

```
@Inject
private Provider<EntityManager> em;
```

This is printed onto console:

`1) Error in custom provider, java.lang.NullPointerException
  while locating com.google.inject.persist.jpa.JpaPersistService
  while locating javax.persistence.EntityManager`

On my `persistence.xml` the persistence-unit is declared as following:

```
<persistence-unit name="simpleRestApplication">

    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>

    <properties>
        <!-- Configuração do driver -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect"
            value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
            value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />

        <!-- Configuração de conexão -->
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/XE" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username"
            value="system" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"
            value="myPassword123" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit"
            value="true" />

        <!-- Configuração do hibernate -->
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode"
            value="auto" />
        <property name="current_session_context_class"
            value="thread" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect"
            value="true" />

    </properties>

</persistence-unit>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [link](https://nozaki.me/roller/kyle/entry/jukito-integration-with-jpa-and) I changed the `configure()` method on `ApplicationModule` to install `JpaPersistenceModule` and start `PersistService`...

```
@Singleton
private static class JPAInitializer {
    @Inject
    public JPAInitializer(final PersistService service) {
        service.start();
    }
}

@Override
protected void configure() {

    install(new JpaPersistModule("simpleRestApplication"));
    bind(JPAInitializer.class).asEagerSingleton();

    // another bindings...

}
```

Now the EntityManager is injected without any error...

```
public class UserDAOImpl implements UserDAO {

    @Inject
    private EntityManager em;

}
```